# issue with unity navimesh and my builded ai code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

firstly i'm sorry if sometimes my English will be a bit incomprehensible, i'll try to do my best.

Actually i'm trying to build a simple AI system with unity Navimesh Component, my goal is :

- NPC will check witch player is nearest to it's position and go there to kill him.
- if target player is facing me run away

my actual code is working but with some issues

```
 private Transform player;
 private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent myNMagent;
 private Transform startTransform;

 public float multiplyBy;
 public Vector3 resultedVector;


 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

     player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
     myNMagent = this.GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent> ();

     RunFrom ();
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {


     //if is not facing got to eat him
    if(!ISFacing())
    {
        GotToEat();      
    }
    else
    {
        RunFrom ();
    }
 }

 public void RunFrom()
 {


     startTransform = transform;

     transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - player.position);

     Vector3 runTo = transform.position + transform.forward * multiplyBy;

     NavMeshHit hit;    



    if(NavMesh.SamplePosition(runTo, out hit, 50, 1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Walkable")))
    {
        transform.position = startTransform.position;
        transform.rotation = startTransform.rotation;

        myNMagent.SetDestination(hit.position);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("not hitting");
    }


 }

 private void GotToEat()
 {
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);
     myNMagent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
 }
 private bool ISFacing()
 {
    float angle = 45;
    float angleToPlayer = Vector3.Angle(player.transform.forward.normalized,( transform.position - player.transform.position).normalized);

     if( angleToPlayer < angle)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     return false;
 }
bool IsHit(out Vector3 result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Vector3 fixedPoint = transform.position + transform.forward * multiplyBy;
        NavMeshHit hit;
        if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(fixedPoint, out hit, 10.0f,1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Walkable")))
        {
            result = hit.position;
            return true;
        }
    }
    result = Vector3.zero;
    return false;
}
```

when NPC is going to reach the corner of my map it won't move anymore will freeze there.

i suppose that i should check if any hitting navmesh is "Walkable" or not, but my function will return always true, so i can't tell to navimesh to go in any other direction..

what i'm missing up?

A video of it

[video](https://youtu.be/v2A5Mt6oZ1w/"Video")

Comment: So the NPC only attacks the player in case: 1- the player is close and 2 - the player is not facing the npc? And in case the player is actually facing the npc, it will run away? Am I right? Besides that, how many players can be target to chase?

Comment: Also, you said: but my function will return always true. What function do you mean?  ISFacing()??

Comment: gameplay will be this :
game start, there is 4 total characters on field, some players some NPC, firstly NPC will go to nearest Player/NPC in case it will enter in certain range and That NPC/Player is facing him it will run away otherwise will eat him.

that's all, i almost know how to build the part of finding nearest one and go to eat him.. but i'm having issue for the run away part